# Migrating a class library to NetStandard1.4 raises an exception during the execution of the Nunit test

Tags: c#, nunit, resharper, .net-standard

I migrated  a class library project to .Netstandard1.4 that include a nuget package System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.2"

The xml .cproj is  described below:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard1.4</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>


      <ItemGroup>           
        <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.2" />                 
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

My unit test (using Nunit version 2.4.6) is still a class library project(.net 4.6.1) (without migration) and reference myStandard1.4 library and it's compiled successfully.

I'm using vs 2017 with Resharper.

When i try to run the  unit test, an exception is fired:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

note it say "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1" not version "4.3.2" that is  uses in NetStandard1.4 library.

I had to modify the  .NetStandard project to support multi target by adding net461 and the exception disappeared and working fine:

```
  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net461</TargetFrameworks>
```

**My question:**

Q1: Why the exception  asks for  "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.1" not version "4.3.2" which i use in NetStandard1.4?

Q2: Why adding the multitarget net461 solved the problem, although [.NET platforms support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-platforms-support) for  .netstandard1.4 support net461?

Q3: Do i have to migrate my unit test class library project to other type? what is this type?

Answer (score 1):

1. The NuGet package version is independent of the assembly version of the contained dll files. The assemblies are versioned in a way that is somewhat compatible with the assemblies present in the .NET Framework.
2. `System.Net.Http` contains a replacement implementation for the .net framework. When you target `net461` in the library, the output contains the appropriate `System.Net.Http` library. If you target a .NET Standard TFM, the library is supposed to be present at the target.
3. You can fix the issue by installing the `System.Net.Http` NuGet package into the consuming project as well. A "new-style" csproj would have picked up the NuGet reference transitively.

Note that there may also be issues when consuming libraries where binding redirects would be necessary, but this only affects new-style csproj test projects at the moment and will be fixed in upcoming test platform releases: [Interface in .NETStandard 1.1 library does not have implementation in .NET 4.61](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43955266/interface-in-netstandard-1-1-library-does-not-have-implementation-in-net-4-61/43955719#43955719)

Comment: I installed manually System.Net.Http but there are other exceptions for other assemblies which i have to install it one by one, which is not logic. Also i added the PropertyGroup as described in your reference but there is no generated .dll.config. It seems that the assemblies of NetStandard is not visible by the project. Where these assemblies are located? How to be visible by the project?

Comment: You can also install `NETStandard.Library` version 1.6.1 or switch the project to use the PackageReference style way of referencing NuGet packages instead of packages.config.

Comment: The PackageReference style way or as i described in my question using mult-target is working.The strange is compilation is successful but the problem at run-time. BTW, also my console application doesn't work with netstandrd. In multi-target the external references are copied with the netstandard.lib and the problem disappear. Can you point me to a document/demo example in official way to use Netstandard class library with nunit or Console application. Thanks

Comment: I don't know of "official" ones. However I suggest trying the latest VS 2017 preview and install a 2.0.0 preview CLI and make the project target `netstandard2.0` instead. This will install the right assemblies automatically. (in preview1 there is/was a nuget package named `NETStandard.Library.NETFramework` you needed to install)

Comment: Thanks. I will try and feed back.

Comment: Microsoft admitted this is a problem and will fix it., expectantly, in NuGet version 4.0.1, the first update to NuGet 4 after VS 2017 ships. https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1582#issuecomment-278937269

Comment: Yeah but this feature got pushed back further, (currently in 4.4 milestone which is after the upcoming VS 2017 15.3 update). Until then, you'd need to add all NuGet packages that you have in a new-style project into packages.config projects as well. (this is what you always had to do for packages.config projects)

Comment: That is a way. Another way is  by converting the NetStandard libray project to multi target,e.g.,  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net461</TargetFrameworks>. I used this way as a work around and  i resolved the bug in the democase https://github.com/OutSorcerer/nuget-dependencies-of-netstandard-library-bug